# How can I delete a specific song and also edit song info from my album list without using DeleteView in Django?

Tags: python, django

**models.py** This is my view file with Album and Song Classes.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_logo = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + '-' + self.artist

class Song(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length =10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    #is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

**views.py** This is my views file for Deleting Song

```
def delete_songs(request, album_id):
    if request.method == "GET":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in the code below:

```
def delete_songs(request, album_id):
    if request.method == "GET":
```

1. You are providing `album_id`, but you are not trying to delete an album. You should provide `song_id` so that you can delete the song.
2. You are checking if the request is GET, but instead you should check if the request is POST. Every time you want to add, update or delete an entry in your database you should always check for a POST request.

Try something like the following:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def delete_song(request, song_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        song = Song.objects.get(id=song_id)
        song.delete()
    return HttpResponse("Song deleted successfully!")
```

If you want to delete an entire album then you should use a different view.

Comment: Upvote for explaining why a POST request is necessary.

Comment: I got this error:

TypeError at /music/6/delete_songs/
delete_songs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'album_id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/6/delete_songs/
Django Version: 2.0.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
delete_songs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'album_id'
Exception Location: C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 126
Python Executable: C:\python\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.4

Comment: Please read my answer and change your code. You are not supposed to get this error if you have changed your code according to the code I have provided. If you have a problem understanding where the code goes then inform here.